# spring mvc; test if redirect is relative

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I want to test if my controller returns correct redirect (relative / context relative / absolute). How can I test it using spring's mockMVC?
can I avoid integration tests with starting server 2 times with different contexts?

Answer (score 1):

If your handler methods always returns String, the redirection is always relative to current servlet context, or absolute. As specified on [Chapter 17.5.3 of Spring Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting):

> A logical view name such as redirect:/myapp/some/resource will
>   redirect relative to the current Servlet context, while a name such as
>   redirect:http://myhost.com/some/arbitrary/path will redirect to an
>   absolute URL.

Hence in my opinion it is sufficient to test the returned String has "redirect:" prefix, and check for the "http://" or "https://" prefix.